# keyup and keydown events invoked with no reasons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a single page application based on jQuery and a lot of jquery plugins like jquery-address and jqueryvalidation.

this application uses hiding and showing divs in order to provide single page application functionality

after moving between pages and working on the application for some time, I got this wierd behavior from chrome where keyup, and keydown events being triggered automatically on every single input in the application where the wrapper of the input has the css display:none property.

this bug does not reproduce on every machine, also if I install the application on different servers it will not happen on all of them.

and to get this bug more wired, if I use incognito mode on the same machine it will not reproduce in the incognito mode while clearing the cache and hard reload on the main window will not solve the issue

I removed all JavaScript code we have, and just kept single html form and the j Query  library  and did a successful ajax call using the console and these events still invoking on the only two hidden inputs I have in the form , while If I make the form visible nothing invoked!!

the final source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: none">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="username">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
</div>
<script src="./js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here a screenshot of the console , you can see I only run 
monitorEvents($("body")[0]);
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000");
and got the events fired

I could not find why these events being triggered, and I don't know why they have the isTrusted: true, also they don't have the key attribute or keyCode or any attribute to tell you what key is being pressed/simulated

BTW: I don't have any extensions/plugins installed in the browser

[image]

Comment: Experiences shows us in programming nothing happened with no reason, There is 100% a problem.

Comment: Have you tried to click on the VM2993 "link" to see where are those events coming from ?

Comment: VM2993 is just the listener from monitorEvents($("body")[0]); when I click it , it shows the code added by the debugger which is (function(e) { console.log(e.type, e); })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after working on these for more than 5 days I found the reason of this behavior, 
it seems that if we submit a form with a password then allow chrome to save the password , and only if we have hidden password input in the page then chrome will invoke all events on the hidden inputs if we have event handler attached to that input

I already reported this bug to chromium project

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797530